# Wrap all <img>'s in <div>, take the alt attribute and add it into a <p> inside

Tags: php, regex, replace

Trying to replace [this jquery code](http://jsbin.com/efidu) with some php server side magic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text img').each(function(){ 
        source = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).wrap($('<div class="caption '+ $(this).attr('class') + '"></div>')).removeAttr('class').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
        $(this).after('<p>' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</p>');
        $(this).attr('src', '/system/tools/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=' + source + '&wl=200&hp=200&q=85&f=jpg');
    });
});
```

All it does is take this:

```
<img class="right" src="blah.jpg" alt="My caption" width="100" height="200" />
```

And replaces it with:

```
<div class="caption right">
    <img src="/system/tools/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=blah.jpg&wl=200&hp=200&q=85&f=jpg" alt="My caption" />
    <p>My caption</p>
</div>
```

The images are scattered throughout a block of textile formated html between `<p>`'s. Something like this:

```
<p>My paragraph text</p>
<img src="image.jpg" />
<p>Another paragraph text <img src="another_image.jpg" /> with more text</p>
<p>And so on</p>
```

It enables users to float images left, right or center and thumbnails are automatically created using phpthumb. I'm assuming I'd need to use regular expressions. I'm new to php and only know frontend coding. How would you attack this?

Comment: It's not the answer to your question, but it is important none the less. The resulting markup you're trying to output is invalid as it has block elements nested within an inline element. A <span> tag should not contain either the <img> tag nor the <p> tag I'm afraid.

Comment: The replacement still has invalid syntax, as the <p> node is closed by a </span>.

Comment: The img element is inline. It's perfectly valid inside an inline element like span or a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this:

```
<?php
$string = '{body}';
$documentSource = mb_substr($string,3,-4);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($documentSource);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//html/body/img') as $node) {
    $node->removeAttribute('height');
    $node->removeAttribute('width');
    $source = $node->getAttribute('src');

    $node->setAttribute('src', '/system/tools/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=' . $source . '&wl=200&hp=200&q=85&f=jpg');

    $pElem = $doc->createElement('p', $node->getAttribute('alt'));

    $divElem = $doc->createElement('div');
    $divElem->setAttribute('class', 'caption '.$node->getAttribute('class'));
    $node->removeAttribute('class');

    $divElem->appendChild($node->cloneNode(true));
    $divElem->appendChild($pElem);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($divElem, $node);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a parser such as [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). In addition with [DOMXPath](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) you can translate the jQuery code nearly one by one:

```
$documentSource = '<div id="text"><img class="right" src="blah.jpg" alt="My caption" width="100" height="200" /></div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($documentSource);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//html/body/*[@id="text"]/img') as $node) {
    // source = $(this).attr('src');
    $source = $node->getAttribute('src');

    // $(this).after('<p>' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</p>');
    $pElem = $doc->createElement('p', $node->getAttribute('alt'));

    // $('<div class="caption '+ $(this).attr('class') + '"></div>')
    $divElem = $doc->createElement('div');
    $divElem->setAttribute('class', 'caption '.$node->getAttribute('class'));

    // $(this).wrap( … );
    $divElem->appendChild($node->cloneNode(true));
    $divElem->appendChild($pElem);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($divElem, $node);

    // $(this).removeAttr('class').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
    $node->removeAttribute('class');
    $node->removeAttribute('height');
    $node->removeAttribute('width');

    // $(this).attr('src', '/system/tools/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=' + source + '&wl=200&hp=200&q=85&f=jpg');
    $node->setAttribute('src', '/system/tools/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=' . $source . '&wl=200&hp=200&q=85&f=jpg');
}
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thats much easier, thank you! The <img> is wrapped by a <div> and captions are shown. Still a few issues though - 

* $documentSource doesn't contain <div id="text"> (it comes earlier in the html), just <p>'s & <img>'s. What should I change the $xpath->query to?
* No attributes are removed from the <img>
* setAttribute on the <img> src doesn't seem to be working. src remains as before.

Answer (score 0):

Some completely untested code:

```
preg_match('|<img class="([a-z\ ]+)" src="([a-z\ ]+)" alt="([a-z\ ]+)" />|i', 'PUT THE EXISTING HTML HERE', $matches);

echo <<<EOT
<span class="{$matches[0]}">
  <img src="{$matches[1]}" />
<p>{$matches[2]}</p>
</span>
EOT; #this should be at the start of line
```

Interested though, in why you can't output the right html in the first place? Loading up a regex engine is not without overhead!

Comment: Alzo you should never parse HTML/XML using a regex. However in this example it can be quite safe as long as you're sure it is always presented the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in a PHP library that mimics jQuerys capabilities natively inside PHP using its DOM extensions.

The project is called [PHPQuery - http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

It could be easily installed through PEAR and usage is similar to jQuery syntax