# PHP DOM - How to insert element in a specific position?

Tags: php, html, dom

In a nutshell, this is what I'm trying to do:

1. Get all `<img>` tags from a document
2. Set a `data-src` attribute (for lazy loading)
3. Empty their sources (for lazy loading)
4. Inject a `<noscript>` tag after this image

1-3 are fine. I just can't get the created `<noscript>` tag to be beside the image correctly.

I'm trying with `insertBefore` but I'm open for suggestions:

```php
// Create a DOMDocument instance
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Loads our content as HTML
$dom->loadHTML($content);

// Get all of our img tags
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

// How many of them
$len = count($images);

// Loop through all the images in this content
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

    // Reference this current image
    $image = $images->item($i);

    // Create our fallback image before changing this node
    $fallback_image = $image->cloneNode();

    // Add the src as a data-src attribute instead
    $image->setAttribute('data-src', $src);

    // Empty the src of this img
    $image->setAttribute('src', '');

    // Now prepare our <noscript> markup
    // E.g <noscript><img src="foobar.jpg" /></noscript>
    $noscript = $dom->createElement("noscript");
    $noscript->appendChild( $fallback_image );

    $image->parentNode->insertBefore( $noscript, $image );
}

return $dom->saveHTML();
```

Having two images in the page, this is the result (abbreviated for clarity's sake):

Before:

```html
<div>
    <img />
    <p />
</div>
<p>
    <img />
</p>
```

After:

```html
<div>
    <img /> <!-- this should be the fallback wrapped in <noscript> that is missing -->
    <p>
        <img />
    </p>
</div>
<p>
    <img /> <!-- nothing happened here -->
</p>
```

Using `$dom->appendChild` works but the `<noscript>` tag should be beside the image and not at the end of the document.

My PHP skills are very rusty so I'd appreciate any clarification or suggestions.

**UPDATE**

Just realised `saveHTML()` was also adding `<DOCTYPE><html><body>` tags, so I've added a `preg_replace` (until I find a better solution) to take care of removing that.

Also, the output I have pasted before was based on the inspector of Chrome's Developer Tools.

I checked the `viewsoure` to see what was really going on (and thus found out about the  tag).

This is what's **really** happening:
https://eval.in/114620

```html
<div>
    <img /> </noscript> <!-- wha? just a closing noscript tag -->
    <p />
</div>
<p>
    <img /> <!-- nothing happened here -->
</p>
```

Comment: Why you don't use [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) class to parse dom??????

Comment: @yonessafari Using third party libraries would be the last resort

Comment: If you want to wrap the `<img />` in a `<noscript>`, why would you use `insertBefore`. This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/873166/979455

Comment: Couple of concerns: You never define your $src (is this intentional?), and running your reduced test case with your example ensures that both of your images are wrapped in <noscript> tags. See https://eval.in/114591. I realise this isn't the intended behaviour either, but can you think of any reason for why your output would deviate this much from the highly simplified test case you've provided here?

Comment: I also figured out that the count is not implemented correctly—count() always returns one, ensuring there's always just going to be one iteration. To get the length of the array, use $images->length.

Comment: @AlexJegtnes Thanks for the reply. Nice tip on the $images->length. The result of your evail.in is not the intended behaviour, no. The only reason I can think it would be so off is that saveHTML is actually injecting DOCTYPE, HTML, BODY. So I'll try to get rid of those first...

Comment: @AlexJegtnes I've forked your eval.in to show what's going on https://eval.in/114620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

So this is how I fixed it:
https://eval.in/117959

I think it's a good idea to work with new nodes *after* they have being inserted into the DOM:

```php
$noscript = $dom->createElement("noscript");
$noscriptnode = $image->parentNode->insertBefore( $noscript, $image );

// Only now work with noscript by adding it's contents etc...
```

Also when it's inserted with "insertBefore" - it's a good idea to save it's reference.

```php
$noscriptnode = $image->parentNode->insertBefore( $noscript, $image );
```

And another thing: I wasrunning this code within Wordpress. Some hooks were being run afterwards which was messing up my markup.